Identify This Movie: Animation between 1990 and 2005
can somebody help me find a movie projected to be between 1990 and 2005? It's an animation movie that I can't remember much of, but I have a few details on it: children fighting in a flying bed at the end of the movie against a black shadow. I guess it was in a dream. I also remember a huge balloon and the boy and girl kissing at the end.  I watched this when I was very young and the movie was the French version. I guess the style was Japanese but I'm not sure. If somebody can help me, it would be great, thanks in advance.

Sounds a bit like an animated Peter Pan movie or TV series, but unless you can give us some more details you will probably not get a better answer :/

Little Nemo: Adventures in Slumberland (1989), I think.
A Japanese/American animated movie where a little boy, Nemo, travels by flying bed to Slumberland.

He spends part of his time in Slumberland in a dirigible (airship aka probably the huge balloon you remember) and shares a kiss with the princess of Slumberland (Camille)-- clip shows dirigible and kiss:



The black shadow is the Nightmare King (of Nightmare Land) who kidnaps King Morpheus (Camille is his daughter) and Nemo has to rescue him.
